# How to Add Tables to RichTextBoxes in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, formatting, richtextbox

How do I add tables to a RichTextBox in VB.NET 2010?

I've tried adding the tables by using RTF codes, but I can't get that to work.  And there is nothing like `richTextBox1.AddTable()` which would make things very simple.  At least, if there is, I haven't found it.

Thanks.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: WinForms.  Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: AFAIK you can add any object to RTF, but it requires a lot of custom programming. I bet you don't want to do it.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/194f563c-205f-41a1-9582-4f03fd3a53c2/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a seperate class for describing how that specific RTB would handle adding a table.  The link from Hans should give you an idea.